# JSON Sharepoint Row Conditional Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have been attempting to format the colour of each row via the date in my $CONTRACTEXPIRES column.

I have the formatting set successfully to be red if the date has passed and green if it has not.

Where there is no date entered into $CONTRACTEXPIRES it is red and I require this to remain grey/none formatted if possible. I have scoured a lot of sites in order to attempt this, but they all refer to column formatting, not the row.

My current code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "<",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "Date()",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "toDateString()",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "Date()",
                    "operands": [
                      "[$CONTRACTEXPIRES]"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "operator": "Date()",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "toDateString()",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "Date()",
                    "operands": [
                      "@now"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont",
      {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": ">",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "Date()",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "toDateString()",
                    "operands": [
                      {
                        "operator": "Date()",
                        "operands": [
                          "[$CONTRACTEXPIRES]"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "operator": "Date()",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "toDateString()",
                    "operands": [
                      {
                        "operator": "Date()",
                        "operands": [
                          "@now"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
          ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `$CONTRACTEXPIRES` column? Date and Time or Single line of text?

Comment: Hi Ganesh. It is formatted as UK date and time (with the time hidden) e.g: 31/03/2021

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting **"Please enter valid view-formatting JSON"** error message. Within sharepoint online the is also a message after "additionalRowClass" which is partly cut off from the screen - the visible message stating **"...applied to the entire row. Supports expressions. Only valid for 'List' and 'Compact List' layouts. Incorrect type. Expected "object".**

Comment: what is the type of $CONTRACTEXPIRES column? Date and Time or Single line of text? Make sure you are entering this JSON in view formatting settings (check image given below in my answer).

Comment: &CONTRACTEXPIRES is date and time format. I have double checked and I am entering the information in the exact way you described with the picture, but unfortunately it is still coming up with the same error decribed in previous comment

Comment: Ah, there was syntax error in expression. I have updated the answer, try JSON codes given in updated answer below.

Comment: Thank you, this now works. There was one small correction in the code:
`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(Number([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]) == 0, '', if(Date(toDateString(Date([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]))) < Date(toDateString(Date(@now))), 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont', if(Date(toDateString(Date([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]))) > Date(toDateString(Date(@now))), 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')))"
}
`

Comment: Literally just to do with the colour still being red if the date was in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this JSON, it should work for you:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(Number([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]) == 0, '', if(Date(toDateString(Date([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]))) < Date(toDateString(Date(@now))), 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont', if(Date(toDateString(Date([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]))) > Date(toDateString(Date(@now))), 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')))"
}
```

There might be a simple way to achieve what you want. But, I am not sure about your column formatted as UK date and time. So, I have kept all `Date()` & `toDateString()` operators as it is.

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

---

**Update**:

Enter JSON code using **Format current view** under **Switch view options** dropdown. Select format view & layout (List) options like below & paste code in advanced mode:

[image]

If above JSON is not working for you, try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(Number([$CONTRACTEXPIRES]) == 0, '', if([$CONTRACTEXPIRES] < @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont', if([$CONTRACTEXPIRES] > @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')))"
}
```

See other ways to check if date column is empty at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)